# Rails Arel Joins Connecting Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying filter when a User's role name matches the Region's name and I'm getting stuck on the Arel join between the three tables.

User has the name, role_id, email, etc. User has_many roles. Role table has the id, and name. Region has name, location. Region does not belong to User.

Example:

- John Smith id: 20, role_id: 15
- Role id:15, name: Pacific Northwest
- Region id: 5, name: Pacific Northwest

So my thought would be user join Region where Region name matches

What I have so far:

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user|
 if user.super_admin?
  self
 else
  joins(:region).where(
  Region.arel_table[:name].matches(Role.arel_table[:id].eq(User.arel_table[:role_id]))
 )
 end
}

def viewable_by?(user)
 return user.super_admin? || user&.role.name == region.name
end
```

I'm referencing the for_user and viewable_by in an Event Controller

```
def index
 @events = search_event.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def search_event
 Event.order(sortable_query)
    .for_user(current_user)
    .includes(:region)
    .advanced_search(
     params[:search],
     params[:region_id]
    )
end

def load_event
 @event = Event.find_by!(id: params[:id])
 raise DeniedError unless @event.viewable_by?(current_user)
end
```

I thought it might be a matches issue so I also tried on instead. Same issue comes up: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String.

The idea is a user has a role assigned to them and can only view those Events that have a name that matches that role.

So if John Smith is logged in he'd only see those Events of Pacific Northwest.

Comment: Are you trying to return a `User` or a `Role`? In your example, are you trying to return the John Smith record given the `Region` record with `name` of "Pacific Northwest"? Where is that code you show located?

Comment: Trying to return User. I'll update the question with the controller use and the viewable method.

Comment: Given `for_user` is a method on the `Event` model, then `Region` is associated with `Event` somehow? BTW, the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) state that "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."

Comment: Event has belongs_to :region, optional: true. Which I'll likely need to remove the optional for this.

Comment: I also have the entire scope and viewable_by? method within a module that is then included within the Event model

Answer (score 2):

I may not have fully grokked your question, but it seems like you ought to be able to do something like:

```
Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :region

  class << self

    def for_user(user)
      return self if user.super_admin?
      joins(:region).where(region: {id: Region.where(name: user.role.name)})
    end

  end
end
```

That should return all `Event`s where the `event.region_id` holds the `id` of any `Region` that has a `name` that matches the `name` in the `user`'s `role`.

You can learn more in [Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) from the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

I see that you have an approach that works using `arel_table`. I'll leave this here as a non-`arel_table`, non-`lambda`, non-`scope` approach.

Also, I'll reiterate from my comment that the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) state:

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.

Answer (score 0):

On a lark I tried, and it worked:

```
joins(:region).where(
              Region.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{user&.role.name}%")
            )
```